# Dimension reduction

Tags: random-forest, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

Can i apply dimension reduction method such as random forest, lasso, factor anaysis or principle compoenet analysis on data which was extracted from two stage stratfied survey

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to CV.

The simple answer to this question is "maybe".

Presumably, you want to know *how* to do this and when it can be done. For that, your question is much too broad.  First, you list four different methods that have different purposes and apply in different cases. This should be four different questions. (I would really only think of PCA as a pure 'data reduction' technique. Random forest is a prediction method, lasso is a variable selection method and factor analysis is a way of finding latent variables).

In addition, you'll have to tell us a lot more about the study design.

Comment: Thank you.  I am doing a secondary data analysis using data extracted from the DHS survey. according to the objective of my research, I have selected around 300 variables. therefore, I thought it would be better to reduce no of variables using above mention method ( I want to select original variable, not dummy variables of original variables, Hence I thought of using random forest). Once again I appreciate your reply, sir.

Comment: syudy design : multistage stratified area probability sample design

Comment: Please put your additional material about the design in your question, rather than in comments.